# Excel Conditional Format based on values in 2D array

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to implement some sort of conditional format or If/Then formula that will return a color (either RED or GREEN) to a cell if a condition is met in another grouping of cells.  For example, I want to tell Excel that if, in a given array of cells (E.g. E5:H11) on one worksheet there is a value (X), then color this cell (on a different worksheet) RED.  If there is no (X) value present in the array, then color this cell (again, on a different worksheet) GREEN.

Can anyone advise the best way to go about this?

Comment: I am not sure if conditional formatting works across sheets.  however if it does, set you your logical check to produce either true or false and use the sheet name in the address reference as well.

Comment: @JoeMalpass nice find, but I think this case is slightly different with the condition having to reference a different worksheet.

Comment: Hi @JoeMalpass, thanks for the help, I am trying to run it on a range of cells not just one and it's failing to pick up the (x) value.  Any ideas?

Comment: So you want it to color green if one or more of a particular range contains an x? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: If one or more of a particular range contains an X value I would like it to color the cell Red.  I tried your formula above on the range $E$5:$H$11 and it is only coloring if the X value is in the first cell of the range (E5) not any others. @JoeMalpass

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MATCH` to do this. Match returns the position of a search term (as a number) within an array, or "N/A" if it is not found.

Conditional formatting uses boolean expressions (formulas that evaluate to true or false) to decide whether to apply the desired formatting or not.

In Excel, any number other than 0 is treated as "TRUE", 0 is "FALSE".

Therefore `=MATCH("X",Sheet2!A1:A10,0)` will return true if there is an X anywhere in the range `Sheet2!A1:A10` and will color the cells.

For your green cells, just add another rule with a version of this formula that specifically looks for "N/A" values: `=ISNA(MATCH("X",Sheet2!A1:A10,0))`

**EDIT** - I see you're searching a 2D array. `MATCH` won't work for that, it can only search 1D arrays (individual column or row). However, you can use `COUNTIF` for 2D arrays.

Fill red if X present: `=COUNTIF($E$5:$H$11,"X")`
Fill green if X not present: `=COUNTIF($E$5:$H$11,"X")=0`

Comment: Thanks Joe, but the formula is not picking up the X value at all and is only returning N/A (no "true" return).  Is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: is X or x in the cells you are searching in.  or is the function not case sensitive?

Comment: @ForwardEd it's not case sensitive. One of `FIND` and `SEARCH` is case sensitive  (I think it's `FIND`) not sure if anything else in Excel is case sensitive.